# Django: Connecting to an API (Oauth)

Tags: django, git, oauth

I want my Django application to connect to an application called Buffer. I've previously connected directly to Twitter using the python-twitter library (http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/), but I'd like to post to more platforms simultaneously, therefore Buffer seems to fit my needs.

However, I have no clue how to achieve this. I've googled around a bit and figured that I need to create an oAuth Client (or some call it Consumer?), but that's basically where I'm at.

My question is therefore as follows:
Where do I start to connect to Buffer using oAuth?

Is there a library that does the work for me, like the python-twitter library? Or do I need to start from scratch? And if that's the case, some guidance is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to interface with a API and had no trouble using [oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2). pydanny's [post](http://pydanny.com/the-sorry-state-of-python-oauth-providers.html) gives you an overview, and some background on why your decision might be harder than anticipated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Care to share the outlines of what you did? I'm kind of a beginner and don't really get too much out of the oauth2-documentation..